# How to fix "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." on a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have the following WPF code and it gives me an exception at "TextBox t = tabItem.Content as TextBox;" the error says "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." How can I fix the exception?

Regards!

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  RichTextBox statusRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
  CloseableTabItem tabItem = new CloseableTabItem();
  tabItem.Content = statusRichTextBox;
  tabItem.Header = "New Tab";
  MainTab.Items.Add(tabItem);
  Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(worker));
  t.Start(tabItem); 
}


public void worker(object threadParam)
{
  CloseableTabItem tabItem = (CloseableTabItem)threadParam;

  TextBox t = tabItem.Content as TextBox; //exception here
  if (t != null)
    Window1.myWindow1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { t.Text = "THIS IS THE TEXT"; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}
```

Comment: The same way people in those other questions with that exception fix it. Didn't you get a duplicate title error perchance and changed it afterwards? Either way, look to the right where it says "Related" ->

Comment: There are definitely **way** too many.

Comment: @H.B. - you have enough rep, pick one and vote to close.

Comment: @Kev: I *do not* want to waste my time looking for the dupe the poster should have looked for. Also it will never be closed as this question is soon burried among its kin, only returning in searches for the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties and methods of UI objects can only be accessed on the thread that created these objects, so when you try to access `tabItem.Content` on a worker thread, it fails.

You can do that instead:

```
TextBox t;
Window1.myWindow1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => t = tabItem.Content as TextBox));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm still unable to write text to the RichTextBox. Can you show me the code for that too?

Comment: @Arya, I suspect that's because the content of the TabItem is a RichTextBox, and you're casting it to a TextBox. RichTextBox is not a subclass of TextBox, so `tabItem.Content as TextBox` returns null

Comment: I fixed that, I put the code here http://pastebin.com/wDmQjvTd but now it says t is an unassigned local variable. Sorry I'm really new to this Dispatcher and threading stuff.

Comment: Just initialize `t` to null when you declare it

Comment: @Arya, did you initialize Window1.myWindow1? And anyway, why do you need that? You can access this.Dispatcher directly...

Comment: the problem was that Window1.myWindow1 was not initialized. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Just a small tip on that if you are sick of passing references to dispatchers around; `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. Also see http://blog.tedd.no/2011/02/25/net-gui-thread-crossing/ and http://blog.tedd.no/index.php/2010/07/10/c-net-winforms-gui-thread-invoke-solution/ for some half-tested prefabs.